# WCF Data Services is not installed for this target framework. (Set up of WCF Console Application Client)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

I am currently trying to set up a WCF Data Service Client using Visual Studio 2013 Desktop. The [following guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868028%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) shows how to set it up as a console application, but every-single-time I try to add a Service Reference VS says:

> Unable to add a service reference to the specified OData feed because
>   WCF Data Services is not installed for this target framework. To install
>   a supported version of WCF Data Services, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=253653.

Is there something I am missing or is it even possible? I've added and tried multiple different different References for the WCF data to no avail. Suggestions?

Comment: Check the .Net framework for the project where you are adding the reference. is the 5.0?

Comment: Did you open the link in error, it direct you to `WCF Data Services Tools`, which I think you are missing

Comment: @DasianSensation I wouldn't use WCF Data Services if I were you, unless you already know :) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/27/future-direction-of-wcf-data-services.aspx

Comment: @Jaycee Unfortunately, our the hosting server from which we need to gather data is using the ODATA Protocol, so we have to use it. :(

Comment: @PranavSingh Looking further into it, it seems we needed to download [WCF Data Service RTM Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39373) and it works. Woot!

Comment: @DasianSensation Well if you are just creating a client of an OData service, then all you have to do is use an HttpContext even if the service is a Wcf Data SErvice. You can consume it independent of any technology.

Answer (score 3):

Though op question has been resolved, I am adding this answer so that it can help any other with the same problem.

The solution is to  to download and install [**WCF Data Service RTM Tools**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39373) as suggested in link provided by Microsoft in error itself.

More more details refer:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39373

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj658961